# Finding duplicates in an ArrayList(JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I'm trying to do a swing application which adds names to an ArrayList and then displays it in Jcombobox.I already did the window and everything but I can't seem to get the hang off detecting duplicate names.

I tried

```
    btnnext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(checkDuplicate(names)==true)
    {
    names.add(txtname.getText());
    txtname.setText("");
    }
    else {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DUPLICATE! do not add");
    }
    }
    });



    public static boolean checkDuplicate(ArrayList<String> list) {
    HashSet set = new HashSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    boolean val = set.add(list.get(i));
    if (val == false) {
    return val;
    }
    }
    return true;
    }
```

It only says that I have duplicate when I already add it to the ArrayList and when I get the message I can't add anything else.

input example:

test

test

---

and then it stops accepting new Strings and only displays the message DUPLICATE! do not add

Comment: This happens because you are basically creating a `Set` view of your `ArrayList` every time you call `checkDuplicate` rather than comparing the item you're trying to add with the existing list. In other words your `checkDuplicate` is written such that it only returns true when a duplicate already exists within the list. You need to compare the new item with the list instead. Step through your logic carefully either with a debugger or by manually writing down the values of your variables and you will see the problem.

Comment: As you said the **checkDuplicate** method was getting me nowhere. I used a contains method and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment:

> This happens because you are basically creating a `Set` view of your `ArrayList` every time you call `checkDuplicate` rather than comparing the item you're trying to add with the existing list. In other words your `checkDuplicate` is written such that it only returns true when a duplicate already exists within the list. You need to compare the new item with the list instead. Step through your logic carefully either with a debugger or by manually writing down the values of your variables and you will see the problem.

You could simply change this line:

`if(checkDuplicate(names)==true)`

to this:

`if(!names.contains(txtname.getText()))`

You don't really need `checkDuplicate` since it's "reinventing the wheel" so to speak. `ArrayList` already provides a [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method that you can use to your advantage.